# How to test this component?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I have a Page level component which implements a component **BookingInformation** with slots.  In the Page component, it's got another component **BookingInformationHeader** with slots. *header* and *default*.

My question is, how should I set up my test so that I can test that the GoogleConversionTrackingImage is visible when `@Reservation.State wasBookingJustMade` changes to true?

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";
import { Reservation } from "@/store/vuex-decorators";
import { BookingInformation, BookingInformationHeader } from "@/components";
import GoogleConversionTrackingImage from './components/GoogleConversionTrackingImage.vue';

@Component({
  components: {
    BookingInformation,
    BookingInformationHeader,
    GoogleConversionTrackingImage
  }
})
export default class ConfirmationPage extends Vue {
  renderTrackingImage: boolean = false;

  @Reservation.State wasBookingJustMade: boolean;
}
</script>

<template>
  <booking-information page-type="confirmation-page" class="confirmation-page">
    <template slot="header" slot-scope="bookingInfo">
      <booking-information-header>
        <template slot="buttons">
          // some buttons
        </template>
      </booking-information-header>
      <google-conversion-tracking-image v-if="wasBookingJustMade" />
    </template>
  </booking-information>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using vue test utils https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/ and chai https://www.chaijs.com/ in your test file you can do something like:

```
    import mount from "@vue/test-utils";
    import expect from "chai";

    const wrapper = mount(BookingInformation,<inner components you want to test>);
    expect(googleImage.exists()).to.be.true;
    wrapper.setData({
        wasBookingJustMade: true,
    });
    const googleImage = wrapper.find("google-conversion-tracking-image");
    expect(googleImage.exists()).to.be.false;
```

You'll probably need to import the page level component as well.
You can give an id to the component you want to find and then search by id.

Comment: I've tried doing something similar.  However, the mount will only mount the Page Level component and stub the children.  The tracking image component is sort of like 3 levels deep.  

Arguably, I could rewrite the page, but I don't have the time to do that right now.

Comment: When you mount, try mounting inner component as well(I've editted my answer):
`const wrapper = mount(BookingInformation,
    BookingInformationHeader,
    GoogleConversionTrackingImage);`